# Dynamically set UIView size depending on height of grouped table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

**Setup**: I have a UIView with a scroll view nested within it. Within the scroll view I have a label, uiimage, and a tableview (grouped). The label, uiimage, and tableveiw are populated by a webservice. The last section in the grouped table view contains text that will never be the same and could be as long as 5 characters to 250+. Also, this view is pushed from a basic tableview (so it has a navigation bar. If that matters at all).

**Expected**: The uiview should extend in height depending on the height tableview extends to. Then I will be able to set the scrollview to accommodate the height I need to be able to scroll.

**Problem**: I'm not quite sure how to approach the issue.  I really only know how to change the height to fixed values, which will not work properly in almost any scenario.

Am I using UIScrollView incorrectly? Do I need to resize the UIView at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to create a UIView programmatically and set it as the header of the UITableView. It works perfectly now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to modify your UIView frame size, which has to be the size of your screen. The UIScrollView frame size must also be the same, it represents the part of its view actually displayed.

What must change is the UIScrollView contentSize, which defines height and width for data inside it ;)

You can calculate it using each inside element's height and by adding the correct margin.
Thus, you could have a UIScrollView content size of 320 * 600, which will let you automatically scroll down.

In fact, you have to display your content independently of the final frame size. If you have a content of 500*500, just display it inside your UIScrollView. Then tell it the size of it's content, and it will automatically set scrolling possibilities if needed.

Comment: Thanks.  I was setting the contentSize of the scrollview, but I wasn't quite sure how to obtain the height I needed.  However, I thought that in order for a scrollview to work, the UIView Frame size had to be larger than the scrollview size. Is this not true?

Comment: No, it's not true, your UIScrollView can be as large as the UIView. And UIScrollView is a UIView, so if the whole screen has to be scrollable, you can directly use a UIScrollView that isn't nested in an UIView ;)

Comment: I removed the initial UIView as you said. Now, the uitableview (which is set at 480 height) gets cut off, which make sense since the height is set to 480.  If I set the height to lets say, 800, it goes further, but the scrollview does not extend far enough sitll. Obviously, setting a defined height for the UITableView is not what I want as I  have no idea what amount of text will be held in the last section. I need the tableview to extend to the maximum length needed and the scrollview should compensate.  I have no idea how to set either of these dynamically.  Your help is truly appreciated.

Comment: You have to set the UIScrollView contentSize to the sum of all your elements height and width.